# Changing the image of a node by clicking-SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want to know how to change the image of a node just by clicking. I have been trying to change the image node like this but it is completely wrong, hope you can help.

```
import SpriteKit

class Scene: SKScene , SKPhysicsContactDelegate{
...
func addNode(){

    var Node:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Node")
    Node.name = "Node"
    Node.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Node.size.width/2)
    Node.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
    Node.removeFromParent()

    Node.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    addChild(Node)

}

...

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    let move = CGFloat(colorAzul.size.width)
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {
    let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
    let node2 = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        if (node.name == "Node") {
            node = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Node2")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with `SKTexture` instead of an image where possible, because you can create nice `SKPhysicsBody` easily. But for your problem you then can change the `SKTexture` of your node easily:

```
var nodeTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player1")

var Node:SKSpriteNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nodeTexture)
```

Then you can change the texture of your node like that:

```
node.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "otherImage")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a SKSpriteNode's image you will have to use its texture property.